# ASP form parameter names being changed to include the master page contentplaceholder

Tags: c#, asp.net, forms, post

Here is my page:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/FBMaster.master" CodeFile="ViewOffer.aspx.cs" Inherits="ViewOffer" %>

<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
    <% 
        FlightBookingWS.FlightBookingSoapClient client = new FlightBookingWS.FlightBookingSoapClient();

        FlightBookingWS.Offer offer = client.GetOffer(Request.Form["OfferID"]);

        if (offer != null)
        {
    %>
    <div class="OfferDiv">
        <span><b>Origin Airport: </b><%=offer.OriginAirport ?? "" %></span>
        <span><b>Destination Airport: </b><%=offer.DestinationAirport ?? "" %></span>
        <span><b>Airline: </b><%=offer.Airline ?? ""%></span>
        <span><b>Available Seats: </b><%=offer.AvailableSeats%></span>
        <span><b>Number Of Connections: </b><%=offer.NumberOfConnections%></span>
        <%
            if (offer.Fare != null)
            {
        %>
        <span><b>Fare: </b><%=String.Format("{0:0.00} {1}", offer.Fare.Value, offer.Fare.Currency) %></span>
        <form runat="server">
            <span>
                <input type="hidden" id="OfferIDField" runat="server" />
                <input type="hidden" id="MessageField" runat="server" />
                <b>Number of Seats: </b>
                <asp:TextBox ID="NumSeatsField" runat="server" Text="1" />
                <asp:Button runat="server" Text="Book now" />
            </span>
        </form>
        <% 
                }
            }
            else
            {
        %>
        Offer not found.
        <%
            }
        %>
        <div id="ErrorBox" runat="server"></div>
    </div>
</asp:Content>
```

Whenever I submit the form, the keys used in the post data are changed from the IDs I wrote to the following ones:

[image: Edited post parameter keys]

Ideally I'd like to access them using the same keys as the IDs of the `input`s they came from, like in normal HTML.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.clientidmode(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: If I change the ClientIDMode the ID becomes the value I want but the name attribute is still overwritten by the server and that gets used in the POST data instead

Comment: I'm not sure if there is a way around that, it is unusual in webforms to post to an external resource like that. Maybe you post back and then do a webrequest to that resource from code where you can control the post data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### That's not how ASP.NET web forms work

When you put markup on a page with the `runat="server"` attribute, you are not actually writing page markup.  You are defining server-side controls that *emit* page markup.  You're not meant to use them like actual HTML elements.

When the page is posted back, the ASP.NET framework looks at the request message and parses all of the values.  It then populates the server-side controls with the necessary data so you can retrieve it easily using ASP.NET syntax.

So, instead of

```
var offerID = Request.Form["ctl100$ContentPlaceHolder1#OfferIDField"]
```

you should simply use

```
var offerID = this.OfferID.Text;
```

This is the way ASP.NET web forms work.

### The old-fashioned way

If you'd rather do it the old-fashioned way, remove the `runat="server"` attribute and write your markup like regular HTML:

```
<INPUT ID="OfferID" Name="OfferID">
```

...and then you can read it the "normal" way:

```
var offerID = Request.Form["OfferID"];
```